# Are pass-by-value structs pushed onto the stack?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

Do the c/c++ compilers push structs by value onto the stack, memcopying hundreds of bytes onto the stack if the programmer specifies a large struct? Does returning structs incur the same penalty?

Comment: BTW, if you defined the compiler & ABI, how would you pass large structures outside of the stack???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will almost certainly do something like a memcpy to copy the struct or class of hundreds of bytes onto the stack if that's what you asked for. If that wasn't the case something like this wouldn't work:

```
std::string s = "A large amount of text";

std::string r = rev(s);
std::cout << s << " reversed is " << r << std::endl; 

...
std::string rev(std::string s)
{
   std::string::size_type len = s.length();
   for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
   {
      swap(s[i], s[len-i]);
   }
   return s;
}
```

This is why it's nearly always recommended to use `const` references when possible, as it passes just a pointer to the object.

Since the above example got objected to, here's another example:

```
class mystring
{
    char s[200];
    size_t len;
  public:
    mystring(const char *aS)
    {
       strcpy(s, aS);
       len = strlen(s);
    }
    char& operator[](int index)
    {
       return s[index];
    }
    size_t length() 
    { 
       return len; 
    }
}

mystring str("Some long string");
mystring rev = rev_my_str(s);

mystring rev_my_str(mystring s)
{
   size_t len = s.length();
   for(size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
   {
      swap(s[i], s[len-i]);
   }
   return s;
}
```

In fact, this will make space for TWO `mystring` objects on the stack, one for `s` going into `rev_my_str`, and one for the return value.

Edit:

Assembler generated by `g++ -O1` [1] for the call to `rev_my_string` as above. The interesting bit is the `rep movsq` along with the setup of `%ecx`, `%rsi` and `%rdi` (count, source and destination, respectively). $26 is the number of 8 byte units that it will copy. 26 * 8 = 208 bytes. `%rsp` is the stack pointer. This is almost exactly how a `memcpy` would look if it was inlined in a simple form [actual `memcpy` most likely has a whole bunch of extra work to deal with unaligned start/end and using SSE instructions, etc].

```
movl    $26, %ecx
movq    %rsp, %rdi
movq    %rbx, %rsi
rep movsq
leaq    416(%rsp), %rdi
call    _Z10rev_my_str8mystring
```

And rev_my_string itself looks like this. Note the `rep movsq` at the bottom of the function. That's where it stores back the resulting string.

```
 _Z10rev_my_str8mystring:
.LFB990:
.cfi_startproc
movq    %rdi, %rax
movq    208(%rsp), %r9
movq    %r9, %r10
shrq    %r10
je  .L5
addq    $1, %r10
movl    $1, %edx
.L6:
movl    %r9d, %ecx
subl    %edx, %ecx
leaq    7(%rsp), %rsi
addq    %rdx, %rsi
movzbl  (%rsi), %edi
movslq  %ecx, %rcx
movzbl  8(%rsp,%rcx), %r8d
movb    %r8b, (%rsi)
movb    %dil, 8(%rsp,%rcx)
addq    $1, %rdx
cmpq    %r10, %rdx
jne .L6
.L5:
movl    $26, %ecx
movq    %rax, %rdi
leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
rep movsq
ret
```

[1] Using higher optimisation than that makes the compiler inline too much of the code (for example the rev_my_string function gets inlined), and it gets very hard to see what goes on.

Comment: The example is not conclusive on Linux/X86-64 where `std::string` contains a single pointer so `sizeof(std::string) == sizeof(void*)` and copy-constructors (or assignment operator) for `std::string` are clever.

Comment: Yes, the example may not be perfect, but it will create a COPY of the whole string - the string in `rev` is a complete new copy of `s` than the one in the other code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Have made a more complex example as well now.

Comment: could maybe you show this two copies in assembly ? - I would be wery much intrested in that proof (!)

Comment: grreat, this two rep movsq was what i was exactly searching for to look on, much tnx

Answer (score 5):

Yes most compilers do push on stack, or copy to stack value-passed structures (and `class`es) . It is generally required by the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (application binary interface) specification relative to the compiler & processor & operating system.

See e.g. [X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) & [System V ABI x86-64](http://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/5100681/system-v-application-binary-interface-x86-64-linux) for details (at least for Linux, x86-64).

Practically speaking, large structures are on the stack, passing (silently) a pointer to them thru registers.

<sup>The ABI defines if these structures are in the caller or callee call frame...</sup>

For two-word sized `struct`-s the Linux x86-64 ABI often passes them (both as argument & as result) thru a pair of registers.

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), try compiling using `gcc -O -S -fverbose-asm foo.c` to get the assembly code `foo.s`; you could use also [GCC MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/#probe_id) or `gcc -fdump-tree-all` to understand the internal (Gimple) representations.

Notice that some quite complex `class` in C++ may have a small value size, because internally a lot of pointers are involved. For instance, on Linux/AMD64 `sizeof(std::string)` is just one (8 byte) word (containing a pointer to some complex stuff), which is probably passed by register. Likewise many containers of the C++ standard library have a small value size (most of the real data being indirectly accessed thru pointers). Details are obviously implementation specific.

Comment: do caller do that - (such pushlike memcopy) ?

Comment: Details depend upon the ABI.